# Circle to Circle collision, checking each circle against all others

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection

I'm currently coding a little circle to circle collision demo but I've got a little stuck. I think I currently have the code to detect collision but I'm not sure how to loop through my list of circles and check them off against one another.

Collision check code:

```
public static Vector2 GetIntersectionDepth(Circle a, Circle b)
    {
        float xValue = a.Center.X - b.Center.X;
        float yValue = a.Center.Y - b.Center.Y;

        Vector2 depth = Vector2.Zero;

        float distance = Vector2.Distance(a.Center, b.Center);

        if (a.Radius + b.Radius > distance)
        {
            float result = (a.Radius + b.Radius) - distance;
            depth.X = (float)Math.Cos(result);
            depth.Y = (float)Math.Sin(result);
        }

        return depth;
    }
```

Loop through code:

```
        Vector2 depth = Vector2.Zero;

        for (int i = 0; i < bounds.Count; i++)
            for (int j = i+1; j < bounds.Count; j++)
            {
                depth = CircleToCircleIntersection.GetIntersectionDepth(bounds[i], bounds[j]); 
            }
```

Clearly I'm a complete newbie, wondering if anyone can give any suggestions or point out my errors, thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You have neglected to state what your actual problem is. Also, instead of comparing radii to distance, compare `a.Radius*a.Radius + b.Radius*b.Radius > xValue*xValue + yValue*yValue`. It is less work, both for you and the computer.

Comment: Superbeast is right. You could further optimize this by only using a `sqrt` operation when your circles actually overlap (to calculate the depth of intersection). `Vector2.Distance` uses `sqrt` which is computationally expensive. It would make a difference if you're checking a lot of circles for intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions look correct assuming bounds is a Circle. The loop through code is also seems correct, as you are avoiding checking the same 2 circles again which is good.

For the collision detection bit, from the source your provided, the function `GetIntersectionDepth(Circle a, Circle b)` will return a zero vector IF the two circles are not colliding, so all you have to do is change your code to this:

```
Vector2 depth = Vector2.Zero;

    for (int i = 0; i < bounds.Count; i++)
        for (int j = i+1; j < bounds.Count; j++)
        {
            depth = CircleToCircleIntersection.GetIntersectionDepth(bounds[i], bounds[j]); 
            if(depth == Vector2.Zero){
                //this means that did not collide
            }else{
                //this means they collided
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nice work. Welcome to GameDev SE!